# Sticky header text with smooth color change on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, sticky

The quest is - add class sticky for h1 tag centered (horizontal and vertical) in the header, and track it to second position and drop in "about" section, with scroll, example (but it is doesn't work) http://codepen.io/AlexanderDolgan/pen/bEjwRP 
So, 
I added sticky class (position:fixed, change top: to 0, reset transform: translate(-50%, 0)) for this element using jQuery, when user start scroll page down.

1) It now remains to make a smooth change text color from white to black with scroll May be use filters? or i can create second h1 text with 0 opacity above, how to change it gradually? 2) add another class in bottom position (green header) and drop text there.

http://codepen.io/AlexanderDolgan/pen/bEjwRP

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--site header -->
    <section class="site-header">
      <!--company name and desc-->
      <div class="hero-text" id="sticky">
        <h1 >Company name</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="about">
      <h2>I want to move the company name here</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quod dolorum doloremque dicta iste a atque iure explicabo? Laborum, magnam?</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  min-height:1000px;
}

body, h1, .wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

// site header
.site-header {
  background: grey;
  height: 50vh;
  min-height: 200px;

  position:relative;
}

// company name and desc
.hero-text {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);

  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


.about {
  text-align: center;
}
.about h2 {
  color:green;
}
.about p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.sticky {
  width: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  transform: translate(-50%,0%);
}
```

JS

```
    $(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#sticky').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            //$('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', float: 'right'});
            $('#sticky').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('#sticky').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help! I can't solve a problem with my first project. If someone give me a hint, it will be great.

Comment: Does your code do the job now? If not, what exactly is the problem you see? What do you want to do? it is not clear from your question

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes partially i complete the challenge - 1) It now remains to make a smooth change text color from white to black with scroll May be use filters? or i can create second h1 text with 0 opacity above, how to change it gradually? 2)  add another class in bottom position (green header) and drop text there. maybe I finished it on the way to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){


    if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
        //$('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', float: 'right'});
        $('#sticky').addClass("sticky");

        $('#sticky h1').css("color","rgb(0,0,0)");

    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass("sticky");

        var colorPic = Math.round((1-$(window).scrollTop()/stickyHeaderTop)*255);
        $('#sticky h1').css("color","rgb("+colorPic+","+colorPic+","+colorPic+")");
    }
});
```

What is happening is that I am changing `h1` color by scroll function using `rgb` color tag. Right now, I am changing color from `white` to `black` and vice versa but you can achieve pretty much any color changes you want. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/YwjgEp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to complete my first project.